# Using internet for bad

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, evil-inclination

Does anyone know of any good shiurim or sefarim to get someone to stop using the internet for bad?

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/shas

Comment: Thanks for the answers, though i am also looking for shiurim

Comment: @DoubleAA lol, I was going to say Mesillas Yesharim

Comment: I have mentored a couple of kids on the issue - I have left a few separate answers to offer you website support, seforim and shiurim. Hatzlocho!

Answer (score 5):

https://guardyoureyes.com/

> *GYE’s goal is to help every Jew who is struggling with inappropriate internet use get the help he needs in the most efficient and
> professional way possible.*
>
> *Guard Your Eyes has already helped many thousands of Jews get back on a path of healing and self-control, by providing free and anonymous
> help for all levels of the struggle.*
>
> *We also have special resources for women and spouses of strugglers.*

> **The 90 Day Program**
> Through our 90 day program we will help you set goals and make a plan
> so you can succeed in reaching long-term freedom. We will give you
> clear guidance and help you keep track of your progress.
>
> **Personalized Programs** There are no "one-size-fits-all" solutions. Once you sign up, you'll get personalized strategies that have the
> highest chance of working for you based on the information you fill
> out during registration.
>
> **Forum and Chatroom**
> Our vibrant forum (with over 250,000 posts!) and chat features allow
> you to learn from other member's successes, and interact anonymously
> with fellow members and volunteers to get support, encouragement and
> advice.
>
> **Phone Conferences**
> With GYE you can participate in the world’s leading Addiction Recovery
> support groups (12-Step and SMART Recovery) anonymously through phone
> conferences. We also have phone conferences for spouses of strugglers.
>
> **Confidential consultations with our expert staff** Once you sign up you'll be able to consult with our in-house experts by phone, chat or
> email. We have dedicated staff and volunteers for males, females and
> spouses.
>
> **Partner & Mentor Program** As a registered member you can find a partner or mentor who you can be in touch with directly by email,
> phone, chat or WhatsApp. The platform makes it easy to find someone
> who is the most likely to be a good match, and will only exchange info
> after both parties agree.

Comment: Although a useful resource, this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

### **OPTION 1 - Web Chaver**

You might want to consider using [Web Chaver](http://www.webchaver.com/).

Essentially you designate a good/trustworthy friend as your 'chaver' and they receive a weekly summary of any potentially risky sites that you may have visited. The fact that you have someone basically checking up on you, is a good form of 'shmira' in unto itself. Or to quote them:

> WebChaver uses the power of a good relationship to help keep you safe online & offline. And of course not only friends, but a parent, spouse or even Rebbe make an excellent chaver too!

The software works in four-steps:

> **1) Screen Monitoring** - The software periodically captures screenshots of your screen activity, even while offline, and stores them securely on your device.
>
> **2) Screenshot Analysis** - Advanced artificial intelligence analyzes those screenshots, on your device, for explicit or questionable imagery.
>
> **3) Screenshot Processing** - The software rates the images, blurs them to protect your privacy, then prioritizes them based on content.
>
> **4) Activity Reporting** - Your weekly report, sent to your chaver, includes a rated selection of blurred screenshots, any circumvention attempts and other activity providing a complete accountability solution.

It has several high-profile haskamos [here](http://www.webchaver.com/haskamos.php).

---

### **OPTION 2 - TAG**

Technology Awareness Group (TAG) is an international organisation geared to helping filter all electronic devices. You can see all their centres and contact numbers [here](https://www.tag.org/). You can either take your devices or they can come to you and help make your phone / laptop etc. internet safe.

A quick snippet from the UK site says:

> *TAG – an acronym for Technology Awareness Group – is a global organisation founded in 2009 by the Vaad Le’Tohar Hamachna – which was a coalition of Rabbanim lead by Rav Matisyahu Solomon Shlita and the Skulener Rebbe Shlita. TAG was established in light of concerns raised at the Kinus Klal Yisroel, about the hazardous nature of modern technology and specifically the internet.
> TAG’s mission is to keep the public informed of the continuously evolving and precarious nature of the internet and modern technology. Additionally, TAG provides guidance and assistance to the public via the TAG Hotline, local TAG Offices, marketing, consulting, outreach, public events, seminars, training, and filter drives.*
>
> *TAG operates globally with 42 locations and hundreds of volunteers worldwide. The TAG Hotline is staffed by volunteers 20 hours a day, answering calls and queries pertaining to the internet and technology related questions.*
>
> *TAG volunteers are able to install and configure many different filters on numerous device types and operating systems. TAG volunteers also provide filter related purchasing advice and respond to complex queries via phone and email.*
>
> *TAG offers physical or software based removal of FM radio capabilities for many MP3 players, and WiFi removal from cameras, laptops, computers and other devices. TAG can also remove or disable video recording features on select camera models upon request.*

You can access some of their regional websites here - [UK](https://tag.org.uk/), [Israel](https://www.tagisrael.org/), [Flatbush](http://tagflatbush.com/), [LA](https://www.taglosangeles.com/), [Atlanta](http://www.tagatlanta.org/),

Comment: These are useful resources but only your other answers actually address the question

Comment: That's because the question was edited - originally it asked what exists online to help

Comment: The question doesn't say it was edit... strange

Comment: I noticed that as well - but as you can see from the previous answer by @chortkov2 he answered in a similar fashion.

Comment: The question has not been edited

Comment: In that case I must have scanned the title 'using internet for bad' and my brain must have triggered on the internet part and sought a solution via the net coupled with @chortkov2's answer. Apologies. Still a good resource though :-)

Answer (score 3):

Some English seforim that may be of interest are as follows:

**[Positive Vision: Real-World Strategies for Shmiras Einayim](https://www.artscroll.com/Products/POVH.html)** by Rabbi Avrohom Neuberger. (You can view some sample pages on the linked page)

The blurb reads as follows:

> *Shemiras eiynayim? Kedushah? They are fantastic concepts - for tzaddikim. But for me? The first thing you should know is: You can do this. The second thing you should know is: You will be much, much happier.*
>
> *With hundreds of thousands of copies in print, The Chofetz Chaim: A Lesson a Day taught us how to make shemiras halashon an integral part of our lives. ,Now the Chofetz Chaim Heritage Foundation, which produced A Lesson a Day, shows us that shemiras eiynayim, even in today's world - especially in today's world - is both vital and doable.*
>
> *These daily readings pack a powerful punch. They're short, illuminating, practical, often funny, and always right on target.*
>
> *What is kedushah and how do we acquire it? What is the single most effective way of avoiding temptations? What factors make it harder to "just say no" ? Positive Vision offers strategies and insights based solidly on Torah hashkafah combined with a deep understanding of the challenges we face in today's world.*
>
> *In the past years Klal Yisrael learned that guarding our tongue leads to innumerable benefits in our personal and communal lives. Now, with the help of these daily readings, we'll enrich every facet of our lives. And, yes, we'll learn to tap into the kedushah that is the birthright of every Jew.*

---

[**The Practical Guide to Shemiras Einayim**](https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/the-practical-guide-to-shmiras-ha-einayim-SHMIRASE.html) by Rabbi Shaul Wagschal

Blurb writes:

> *A halachic guide for men*
>
> *The immodesty that surrounds us presents one of the most formidable challenges of our time.*
>
> *How do we protect ourselves?*
>
> *The answer is: Take the first step and learn the halachos of guarding your eyes.*
>
> *Reb Yisroel Salanter advised that one of the best ways to overcome the yetzer hara is to study that subject’s halachos. This invaluable guide by renowned author and posek Rabbi Shaul Wagschal, z”l, provides a clear and simple way to do just that.*
>
> *Features a helpful halachic summary chart!*

---

**[Enlighten Our Eyes](https://judaicaplaza.com/products/6768143)** by Rabbi Yosef Shlomo Goldschmidt

> *The sefer "Veha'eir Eineinu" has inspired and encouraged people from a wide-spectrum of backgrounds to strengthen their commitment to Shmiras Einayim. 80,000 copies have been published making it a popular and unique classic.Rabbi Zev Leff, Rabbi of Moshav Matityahu, wrote the following: "The author deals with a sensitive but necessary subject in a most delicate, refine and masterful manner. He presents solid practical advice as how to achieve this most important quality. I highly recommend this work to everyone who wants to be aided in fulfilling this crucial area of Torah observance. I commend Rabbi Goldschmidt for a truly magnificent contribution to Torah literature."*

Answer (score 3):

A few Shiurim to get one started...

1. On [Guard Your Eyes](https://guardyoureyes.com/news/item/shmiras-einayim-audio-shiurim) - over 400 shiurim available via phone.
2. YU Torah - ['SHMIRAS EINAYIM - a little less curious, a lot more s'char'](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/837483/rabbi-noam-singer/shmiras-einayim-a-little-less-curious-a-lot-more-s-char/) by Rabbi Noam Singer
3. [Teshuva on Shovevim - Shemiras Einayim](http://www.torahdownloads.org/shiur-1011583.html) - Rabbi Zecharia Wallerstein
4. [Nowhere to Turn - Internet Addiction](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?v=122892)

Answer (score 1):

Shovavim -The power of the eye- Rabbi Avi Weisenfeld

[Drinking the salty water](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?a=73827)

[Rising to the challenge](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?a=74270)

[Milchemet HaYetzer- You are not alone](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?a=75680)

[Picking up the pieces](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?a=76183)